# How to Create Google Calendar Events Straight from Gmail

Tags: email, gmail, google-calendar-api

I want to write an email in [gmail](http://www.gmail.com/) about timings for a meeting. But I was wondering if the recipients could directly add it to their google calender like as below -

[image]

I have gone through many blogs but all of them are about adding a new event in the google calender and then share it with recipients but I want to know if there is any shortcut to it that we can directly add an event while composing an email. Somebody, please suggest me how to do it.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359516/creating-google-calendar-events-from-gmail) if it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @KENdi. That questions is different from my question, there they are talking about using Google's calender API's in his website i guess. But I just want to add a date in email msg, so that it can be added directly to the google calender of recipient.